# MYSQL installation errors with docker

Tags: mysql, bash, docker

I am trying to install mysql from a docker container on rhel6.
This is my dockerfile:

```
#HELLO
FROM rhel6
MAINTAINER xxxx

ADD ./perl /usr/bin/
RUN whereis perl
RUN ls -lrt /usr/bin/
RUN yum install http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-community-release-el6-5.noarch.rpm -y
RUN yum update
RUN yum install mysql
ADD ./startup.sh /opt/startup.sh

EXPOSE 3306

CMD ["/bin/bash", "/opt/startup.sh"]
```

This is my startup script:

```
if [ ! -f /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1 ]; then

    mysql_install_db

    /usr/bin/mysqld_safe &
    sleep 10s

    echo "GRANT ALL ON *.* TO admin@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'changeme' WITH GRANT OPTION; FLUSH PRIVILEGES" | mysql

    killall mysqld
    sleep 10s
fi

/usr/bin/mysqld_safe
```

When i run my docker container, this is the error i am getting:

```
[xxxx ~/mysql]$ sudo docker run -i -t -p 3306:3306 mysql12 /bin/bash
bash-4.1# service mysqld start
mysqld: unrecognized service
bash-4.1# ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  lost+found  media  mnt  mysql-community-release-el6-5.noarch.rpm  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  selinux  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
```

This is the output i see when i run docker run -i -t

```
[xxxx/mysql]$ sudo docker run -i -t 3e7ed89e7d4a 
/opt/startup.sh: line 3: mysql_install_db: command not found
/opt/startup.sh: line 5: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: No such file or directory
/opt/startup.sh: line 8: mysql: command not found
mysqld: no process killed
/opt/startup.sh: line 14: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: No such file or directory
```

I dont have much experience installing software. Am i missing anything in my steps?
This has previously worked on centos.
I believe with the procedure i followed mysqld is not getting installed.
Can experts suggest me tips?

MOST RECENT ERROR:

```
---> Package mysql-community-client.x86_64 0:5.6.22-2.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Sys::Hostname) for package: mysql-community-client-5.6.22-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(IPC::Open3) for package: mysql-community-client-5.6.22-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Getopt::Long) for package: mysql-community-client-5.6.22-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(File::Temp) for package: mysql-community-client-5.6.22-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Fcntl) for package: mysql-community-client-5.6.22-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Exporter) for package: mysql-community-client-5.6.22-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/perl for package: mysql-community-client-5.6.22-2.el6.x86_64
---> Package mysql-community-common.x86_64 0:5.6.22-2.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/perl for package: mysql-community-client-5.6.22-2.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-5.6.22-2.el6.x86_64 (mysql56-community)
           Requires: perl(Sys::Hostname)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-5.6.22-2.el6.x86_64 (mysql56-community)
           Requires: /usr/bin/perl
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-5.6.22-2.el6.x86_64 (mysql56-community)
           Requires: perl(Getopt::Long)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-5.6.22-2.el6.x86_64 (mysql56-community)
           Requires: perl(IPC::Open3)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-5.6.22-2.el6.x86_64 (mysql56-community)
           Requires: perl(Exporter)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-5.6.22-2.el6.x86_64 (mysql56-community)
           Requires: perl(File::Temp)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-5.6.22-2.el6.x86_64 (mysql56-community)
           Requires: perl(Fcntl)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
2015/01/16 10:23:43 The command [/bin/sh -c yum install mysql] returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: Why don't you run the container with /bin/bash so you can explore and see if mysqld is in fact installed? Once your image is built, just run `docker run -t -i my_repo/my_image /bin/bash`. You can now explore inside the container with Bash and see what's missing.

Comment: yes i ran the run command. look at my edited question.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you installed mysql-community-release-el6-5.noarch.rpm which I see is available at http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/yum/.

This is just a package to install the repositories as opposed to actual mysql. you should do

```
yum install http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-community-release-el6-5.noarch.rpm -y
yum update
yum install mysql
```

after installing that package or download the rpm from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/:

Comment: I tried to use yum install directly. Yet i see errors. I edited my post with the lastest Dockerfile and errors.

Comment: I still don't see an install of mysql in your docker file.

Comment: i made the changes. i am getting an error saying that it cannot find perl though i added the perl from local file system/

Comment: Why not yum install perl?

Comment: Also why aren't you using the offical mysql container? https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/mysql/

Comment: yum install perl says no such package.

Comment: I need to customize a lot of things on top of it. That is why not doing it.

Comment: You could use it as a base image and add your customizations to your downstream image